# Problem using function ranef in R on a mblogit model

Tags: r, dataframe, function, regression

I am currently studying a logit model in R, I am using the [mblogit](https://rdrr.io/cran/mclogit/man/mblogit.html) model from the [mclogit](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclogit/index.html) library. I want to study the random effects using the function [ranef](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-32/topics/ranef) from the library [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html).

However, I get the following error

> Error in UseMethod("ranef") :
> no applicable method for 'ranef' applied to an object of class "c('mmblogit', 'mblogit', 'mmclogit', 'mclogit', 'lm')"

I was wondering if someone could point me to a function that does something similar to `ranef` that works on `mblogit` objects.

The following code is a toy example of the issue. The program ends with the same error.

```
library(mclogit)
library(tidyverse)
options(warn=-1)

mi_df <- data.frame(
  "factor" = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "a"),
  "category" = c("1", "1","1", "2", "2", "2"),
  "province" = c("aa", "bb", "aa", "bb", "aa", "bb"),
  "number1" = c(1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 4.5, 3.6),
  "number2" = c(6, 4, 9, 4, 2, 6)
  )

mi_df$category <- relevel(as.factor(mi_df$category), ref="1")

modelo_multinomial0 <- mblogit(category ~  factor + number1+number2 , random = ~ 1  | (province), 
                               data=mi_df, maxit = 30, epsilon = 1e-04)
summary(modelo_multinomial0) 
confint(modelo_multinomial0) 

library(lme4)
ranef(modelo_multinomial0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From digging through `str(modelo_multinomial0)`, it looks like `$random.effects` *might* be what you want:

```r
modelo_multinomial0$random.effects[1,1][[1]]
            [,1]
[1,] 5.418201e-41
[2,] 6.020224e-42
```

I would experiment with some larger examples to see if the dimensions and values of this component match what you expect.